# Cannot Catch then Handle Mongoose / MongoDB error within Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, error-handling

I want to let the front end know if there is a validation issue such as a duplicate submission ID. I have ready many stack posts already and tried the various solutions in this code...

in short none of the catch methods are catching an error. It as though mongo or mongoose is throwing it before my code gets a look in :(

here is my code

```
exports.createFinishedJob = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        console.log('createFinishedJob req.body', req.body);
        const finishedjob = new FinishedJob();
        if (req.body.jobSubmissionId) { finishedjob.jobSubmissionId = req.body.jobSubmissionId };
        if (req.body.customerId) { finishedjob.customerId = new ObjectId(req.body.customerId) };
        finishedjob.finishedjob = req.body.finishedjob;
        if (req.body.other) { finishedjob.other = req.body.other };
        console.log('createFinishedJob', finishedjob);

        let error;
        try {
            await finishedjob.save()
                .catch(err => console.log("HALLO err", err));
            // if (res && doc) {
            //     return res.json(doc);
            // } else {
            //     return doc
            // }
        } catch (err) {
            error = err;
            console.log("createFinishedJob error", error)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Something went wrong")
        console.error(err)

    }
};
```

here is the error:-

```
(node:85241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: Genaich.processingjobs index: jobSubmissionId_1 dup key: { jobSubmissionId: "1006006" }
    at /Users/urfx/phos-code/genaich/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/insert.js:50:33
    at /Users/urfx/phos-code/genaich/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/command.js:84:64
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:85241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

here is the model

```
const  mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const  Schema  =  mongoose.Schema;
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema;
const SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const  finishedjobSchema  =  new Schema(
    {
        customerId: { 
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            required: false 
        },
        jobSubmissionId:{
            type: String, // if we don't get one from the customer use payment / order number
            unique: true,
            index: true
        },
        trashed: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        finishedjob: {
            type: Object
        },
        other: {
            type: SchemaTypes.Mixed // to start the ball rolling 
        }

    },
    { timestamps: true });

let  FinishedJob  =  mongoose.model("FinishedJob", finishedjobSchema);
module.exports  =  FinishedJob;
```

Comment: Post your schema. You have a simple `E11000 duplicate key` error on `jobSubmissionId`. This will be easy to debug once I see your schema.

Comment: yes I want the E11000 error. my problem is once generated I want to trap the error...  and tell the client application 

the schema is not the issue. submissionID is unique and index hence it works as I need it to and throws the error. or are you proposing I trap the error in the schema?

Comment: Is your intention to return json to the user if there is a duplicate key error?

Comment: @jQueeny my aim is to handle the error by returning a json message via my express api.

Comment: OK good. Let me have a look.

Comment: OK I tested your code. Works nicely many thanks. Accepted your answer. I also added an answer to show how I implemented your good solution. sending you a coffee :-)

Comment: Happy it helped. You're implementation looks useful for others too.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one would be to use the `Model.create()` method and just catch any errors that it throws. The `Model.create()` is just like a `const doc = new Model();` +  `doc.save()` all in one method. Use like so:

```js
exports.createFinishedJob = async (req, res) => {
   try {
        // If this fails for any reason it will throw to the catch block
        const finishedjob = await FinishedJob.create({
            jobSubmissionId: req.body.jobSubmissionId,
            customerId: req.body.customerId,
            finishedjob: req.body.finishedjob,
            other: req.body.other
        });
        // This will only return if the document was created successfully
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Job Created'
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // Check for the E11000 duplicate key error
        if(err.code === 11000){
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: err.message
            });
        }else{
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error on server'
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Option two would be to quickly check if a `Finishedjob` with `jobSubmissionId` already exists and return the error message early. However, if there is no match then you still need to create the new document again which means two calls to the database so if you are handling thousands of new requests to that route per minute then obviously less efficient. Use like so:

```js
exports.createFinishedJob = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const existingFinishedjob = await FinishedJob.findOne({
           jobSubmissionId: req.body.jobSubmissionId
        });
        if (existingFinishedjob){
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Already exists'
            });
        }
        const finishedjob = await FinishedJob.create({
            jobSubmissionId: req.body.jobSubmissionId,
            customerId: req.body.customerId,
            finishedjob: req.body.finishedjob,
            other: req.body.other
        });
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Job Created'
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error on server'
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will test and revert today. I do already have an upsert style method which checks for existing jobs, and then uses the create function. Just waiting for the coffee to kick in. Really appreciate your answers. TY

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks @jQueeny

Your first suggestion using "create" does what I need with a slight tweak I should have mentioned I also wanted to return the successful new doc too. I couldn't put all this in the comments.

```
/**
 * THANKS @jQueeny for this working solution to handling 11000 with a catch
 * using create instead of save... seems I had the clue in my method name to 
 * start with
 * @param {*} req 
 * @param {*} res 
 * @returns duplicate error if the submissionId already exists otherwise returns the new "finished" document
 */
exports.createFinishedJob = async (req, res) => {
   try {
        // If this fails for any reason it will throw to the catch block
        const finishedjob = await FinishedJob.create({
            jobSubmissionId: req.body.jobSubmissionId,
            customerId: req.body.customerId,
            finishedjob: req.body.finishedjob,
            other: req.body.other
        });
        // This will only return if the document was created successfully
        if (res && finishedjob) {
            console.log({"success":finishedjob});
            return res.status(200).json({"success":finishedjob});
        } else {
            return finishedjob
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // Check for the E11000 duplicate key error
        if(err.code === 11000){
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: err.message
            });
        }else{
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error on server'
            });
        }
    }
};
```